# What are the pros and cons of specifying redundant API endpoints?

Tags: laravel, api, rest

I have the following API endpoints:

```
Route::post('/jobs', [JobController::class, 'store']);
Route::patch('/jobs/{id}', [JobController::class, 'update']);
Route::delete('/jobs/{id}', [JobController::class, 'destroy']);
```

Should I add the following redundanct endpoints? Redundant in the sense that they point to the same controller functions.

```
Route::post('/projects/{projectId}/jobs', [JobController::class, 'store']);
Route::patch('/projects/{projectId}/jobs/{id}', [JobController::class, 'update']);
Route::delete('/projects/{projectId}/jobs/{id}', [JobController::class, 'destroy']);
```

I personally find specifying resources as top-level resources rather than nested resources more convenient as there is no need to pass in (useless) parent locators.

Is there any benefit to defining these additional routes just for the sake of having a RESTful API?

Answer (score 0):

My common sense says that if I see the slug `/projects` at the beginning of an URL, the action will be related to that model, in this case, `Project::class`.

On the other hand, if your `Job::class` is related to your `Project::class` through a foreign key, you have all that you need to reach the Job's project, in that case, I see no sense to sending `{projectId}` on the URL.

In fact, what could happen if you send a `{projectId}` that is not related to the `{id}`. You will need to validate both values and do an extra effort by writing validations.